# Any way to speed up npm run test-compiled in Github Actions?

Tags: npm, github-actions

I have a Github Actions workflow that loops through a list of services and runs `npm run test-compiled` sequentially and takes 30 minutes to finish.

I am trying to see how I can improve the time taken to complete this step. One option I thought of was to create multiple jobs in the workflow and have each job run the test concurrently, however this always fails as files from the node install are missing.

Are there any recommendations on how to shorten the time needed for the workflow to complete?